# How can I see a list of running apps with root privileges

Tags: root-access

I'm running CyanogenMod and recently the # sign showed up in my status bar. Now I wonder which program / app is causing this / is using root access. Is there a way to show a list of running apps which use root privileges?

Comment: `ps | grep root`. The process names (last column) might include the package name (as a path) of the app from which you can find which app it is. (It also displays other kernel dameon process, ignore them). Force stop those apps one by one & see if the '#' symbol goes goes away..

Comment: *[Actually you can see the processes running as root with CM12.1's root. When you see that icon, opening the quick access notification bar will also have a super user icon, which when pressed, will tell you which app and package is using it.](https://www.reddit.com/r/cyanogenmod/comments/3g44di/what_is_this_hash_icon_in_status_bar_and_how_to/ctv7915)*

Comment: Hmm I'm running CM12.1 but when I open the quick access bar the super user icon disappears.

Comment: I did, but killing the processes (xprivacy) did not help as the either got not stoped or restarted immediately. But thanks for the answer anyway. It increases my belief that xprivacy is causing this sign.